# Split Erlang UTF8 binary by characters

Tags: string, utf-8, binary, erlang

How to split binary Erlang string treating its data as UTF8 characters?

Let's say we have a binary, which should be split into two parts, and the first part should contain first two UTF8 characters. Here are few examples:
`<<"ąčęė">>` should become `[<<"ąč">>, <<"ęė">>]`

`<<"あぁぅうぁ">>` should become `[<<"あぁ">>, <<"ぅうぁ">>]`

Comment: I am sorry,but i do not understand what you want to get a result?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to split a binary UTF8 string based on the number of characters, not bytes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To just split a utf-8 encoded binary string into two parts with the first part containing the first two characters and the second part the rest you could use the function:

```
split_2(<<One/utf8,Two/utf8,Rest/binary>>) ->
    %% One and Two are now the unicode codepoints of the first 2 characters.
    [<<One/utf8,Two/utf8>>,Rest].
```

Matching against a binary with a utf8 will extract the first utf-8 encoded character and return the unicode codepoint as an integer which is why we must build the resultant binary of the first two characters. This function will fail if there are not 2 utf-8 encoded characters first in the binary.

The difference between a bitstring and a binary is that the size of a binary must be a multiple of 8 bits while a bitstring can be any size.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What about arbitrary number of characters to split by?

Comment: @cnduo I'm afraid you have to use recursive function, that extracts characters one by one, because you cannot see how many bytes correspond your number of characters, in other words, you have to parse all the utf8 characters

Comment: Yes, it is as @kitty says. You can only explicitly pluck characters from the front of the binary, here I was taking 2, so if you want an arbitrary number then you need to recurs over the binary.

Answer (score 0):

Still, it's unclear for me, but I think this would make the trick:

```
Eshell V6.2  (abort with ^G)          
1> Input = <<"ąčęė">>.                
<<"ąčęė">>                            
2> L = [X || <<X:2/binary>> <= Input].
[<<"ąč">>,<<"ęė">>]                   
3>
```

**UPDATE:** This one will split it into `S, TheRest`:

```
%% S is the number of characters you want
split_it(S, Bin) when S > 0 ->
  case Bin of
    <<P:S/binary, R/binary>> -> [P | split_it(infinity, R)];
    <<>> -> [];
    _ -> [Bin]
  end.
```

Comment: What I mean is that data should be indexed by characters, not bytes or bits. I'm afraid your snippet won't work for strings with uneven length, and also the result should be made of binaries, not bitstrings.

Comment: @cnduo you should formulate the question more clearly. 
Show that you want to see as a result.Can replace the above code 2 for 1 and get: [<<5>>,<<"\r">>,<<25>>,<<23>>]

Comment: Please check out my latest edit. Removed possibly redundant and misleading information.

Answer (score 0):

happen to need a function like this. and here is what I end up with:

```
trunc_utf8(Utf8s, Count) ->
    trunc_utf8(Utf8s, Count, <<>>).
trunc_utf8(<<>>, _Count, Acc) -> Acc;
trunc_utf8(_Utf8s, 0, Acc) -> Acc;
trunc_utf8(<<H/utf8, T/binary>> = _Utf8s, Count, Acc) ->
    trunc_utf8(T, Count - 1, <<Acc/binary, H/utf8>>).
```